# Can we run Sidekiq for Rails 2.3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

In one of the Rails application I'm working, we need to implement background processing. Nowadays, Sidekiq is very popular.

But, we are using `Rails 2.3.18` and `ruby 1.8.7` and we cannot change it as of now. So, can we use any Sidekiq version compatible with our app and without any issues?

If possible, please mention the appropriate version of Sidekiq also. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No. But I upgraded the Rails and Ruby version for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No version of Sidekiq has ever supported MRI 1.8 or Rails 2.x.  MRI 1.9 and Rails 3.x are supported by Sidekiq 2.x.

Answer (score 3):

The docs at https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq are very clear:

> I test with the latest MRI (2.1, 2.0) and JRuby versions (1.7). Other versions/VMs are untested but might work fine. MRI 1.9 is no longer supported.
>
> All Rails releases starting from 3.2 are officially supported.

Therefore for Rails 2.3 with Ruby 1.8 the answer is: No.

Comment: Hi, Is there any alternate solution to run a background process?

Comment: @Abhiram : Two other well known gems for background jobs are [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) and [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).